# Build a free-style software project - code description

Tags: jenkins

During job creation in Jenkins, there comes an option **Build a free-style software project**.

May I ask where the implementation of this function is done in source code?

Comment: grep is your friend :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/807e3c81d41c7d2d86bfa0469289e070fea42a6c/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/FreeStyleProject.java) is the implementation of that function.